# node.js cluster get all workers info

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

According to node.js documentation, the cluster class should have a workers object and it can be iterated like this:

```
Object.keys(cluster.workers).forEach((id) => {
     cluster.workers[id].on('message', messageHandler);
  });
```

but for some reason when I try this in my code, cluster.workers is undefined (process launched with pm2)

```
var cluster     = require("cluster");
console.log("cluster status : " , cluster.isMaster ?  " master " : " slave " , " - worker id "  , (cluster.worker ? cluster.worker.id : " none ") , " workers : " , cluster.workers);
```

I got output like this:

```
cluster status : slave - worker id 15 workers : undefined
cluster status : slave - worker id 14 workers : undefined
```

so I guess workers are only available from master , but is there a way to communicate with other slaves for a slave ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the 'workers' property is only available in the master process (see [latest documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_workers)).

I don't think there's any way for workers to communicate directly with each other - all communication goes via the master.

You can pretty easily use the 'message' mechanism to set up a system for using the master as a relay to route messages between workers. I'm not sure quite what you're trying to achieve, but here's an overview.

The idea of the first chunk of code that you posted is that you run it in the master and it means that the "messageHandler" callback is called when the master receives a message from any of its workers. In fact, you can achieve the same thing by doing:

```
cluster.on('message', messageHandler);
```

The messageHandler function is passed a parameter identifying which worker sent the message.

Similarly, workers can listen for messages from the master by doing this:

```
process.on('message', workerMessageHandler);
```

You can send messages by doing:

```
// Worker: send message to master
process.send({ cmd: 'notifyRequest', data: 'somedata' });

// Master: send message to specific workers
worker.send({ data: 'somedata' });
cluster.workers[0].send({ whatever: 'something' });
```

The message can be a string or an object (which will be serialized to JSON).

Comment: Actually, I need to perform a task on a single worker, I m currently working on a solution like this var numCPU   = require("os").cpus().length; if ((!cluster.isMaster && (cluster.worker.id % numCPU) == whatever_between_0_and_numcpu_minus_1 ) { // do the job } , seem to work